# How to get logged in user's id from session in LuminusWeb

Tags: clojure, luminus

I've just saved the current logged-in user in session. Now how do I get user's id from session in `Selmer` templates?. Thanks

```clj
 (defn login-form [{:keys [flash]}]
  (layout/render
   "login_form.html"
   (merge (select-keys flash [:id :pass :errors]))))

(defn authenticate [id pass]
  (when-let [user (db/get-user {:id id})]
    (when (hashers/check pass (:pass user))
      id)))

(defn login! [{:keys [params]}]
  (if-let [id (authenticate (:id params) (:pass params))] ;TODO: Refactor
    (do
    >>>>>>>>>  (update (response/found "/") :session {:id id}))
    (layout/render "login_form.html" {:invalid-credentials? true})))

(defroutes auth-routes
  (GET "/accounts/login/" request (login-form request))
  (POST "/accounts/login/" request (login! request)))
```

### Update

I've updated my login function. and it works.

```
 (defn login! [{:keys [params session]}]
  (if-let [id (authenticate (:id params) (:pass params))] ;TODO: Refactor
    (-> (response/found "/")
      (assoc :session
        (assoc session :id id)))
    (layout/render "login_form.html" {:invalid-credentials? true})))
```

To print the user's id, I've changed the home-routes.

```
 (defn home-page [opts]
  (layout/render "home.html" opts))

(defroutes home-routes
  (GET "/" {:keys [flash session]} (home-page (or flash session))))
```

Now I can print user's `id` in `home.html` template. But If I use any other url then user's `id` stopped `displaying``.

**Question** > So do I need to pass `{:keys [flash session]}` in every routes?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `wrap-identity` middleware which Luminus provides by making sure it's in your `wrap-base` stack, then change `:id` to `:identity` in your `session`. You can now call `(layout/render "home.html")` (even without providing opts!) and you can access the identity using `{{identity}}`

Comment: I'm trying like `{{id}}` in `Selmer` templates. But no luck.

Comment: Thanks for update. I tried but I'm not able to print the user's id.